# How to present files like Word, Excel and PowerPoint to be downloaded by the user ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET C# app, have a table in which I defined a binary column to store files (column name attFile) also saved the file name, file size and Mimetype, most of the files are JPG, PNG, PDF, I have no problem to display those files to the user in a way that they can preview the image, but with files like Excel, Word PowerPoint, I don't know how to present them so the user can download it, the way I'm doing this is

```
View
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.MimeType == "application/pdf")
    {
        <div>
            <object data="@Url.Action("MyImage", new { id = item.id })" 
                              type="application/pdf" 
                              width="250" height="150">
            </object>
        </div>
    }
    else if (item.fotoMimeType == "image/jpeg")
    {
        <div>
            <img src="@Url.Action("MyImage", new { id = item.id })" 
         alt="Picture" style="width:150px"  />
        </div>
    }
    else if (Excel, Word, PowerPoint)
    {
        don't know what to do
    }
}

Controller
public ActionResult MyImage(int id)
{
   AttFile xFile = _db.AttFile.SingleOrDefault(x => (x.id == id));
   return File(xFile.attFile, xFile.MimeType );
}
```

My idea is to show an image that says Excel File, Word File, PowerPoint File, so the user can download this file, or maybe a link with the filename, but I don't know how.

Can anyone help on this subject?

Comment: Are you asking what mime type Word and Excel files are?  http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, a popup dialog appears which asks the user if he want to save the file or open it:

```
    public void DownLoad(string FName)
    {
        string path = FName;
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
        }

    }
```

the line: Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
told which type of file to download. this type is for docx file.